# Getting Site Collection admin email address if ReadOnly enabled

Tags: site-collection, runwithelevatedprivileges, read-only

I have a site collection which is in read only state. I need to get Site Collection administrator's email address. I've tried to use elevated privileges, but still get "Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation". 
The only working solution is to disable "Read Only" state for span when reading email address occurs.

Does anyone know another solution?

Comment: Have you tried enabling unsafe updates? (just guessing here)

Comment: can you share the code?

Comment: I Didn't find elegant solution, so disable "Read Only" and enable it again after email has been read.